# Exception in Tkinter callback

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, arduino, firmata

I wrote a code to read an analog value from my arduino and monitor the results in a simple Python application, but when I hit the button "start" in my app, this error appeared: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last)

and the the compiler located the error in this instraction: analoglabel.config(text=str(pin.read()))

sorry I coudn't fill all the error message

and this is my code:

```
import pyfirmata
from pyfirmata import util
import Tkinter
from time import sleep

def press():
  it = util.Iterator(board)
  it.start()
  while True:
    if flag.get():
        analoglabel.config(text=str(pin.read()))
        analoglabel.update_idletasks()
        root.update()
    else:
        break
    board.exit()
    root.destroy()

def exit_command():
 flag.set(False)

port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
board = pyfirmata.Arduino(port)
sleep(5)
pin = board.get_pin('a:0:i')

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Analog read by hamzawi")
root.minsize(300, 50)

startbutton = Tkinter.Button(root,
                          text="START",
                          command=press)
startbutton.grid(column=1, row=2)

exitbutton = Tkinter.Button(root,
                        text="EXIT",
                        command=exit_command)
exitbutton.grid(column=2, row=2)

label = Tkinter.Label(root,
                   text="The value is: ")
label.grid(column=1, row=1)

analoglabel = Tkinter.Label(root, text=" ")
analoglabel.grid(column=2, row=1)

flag = Tkinter.BooleanVar()
flag.set(True)

root.mainloop()
```

please I need help!! and thanks a lot

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You're going to have to tell us the actual error for us to be able to help you.

Comment: here is part 1because it's long: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/hamzawi/Documents/Python_projects/potentioPython/pot.py", line 13, in press
    analoglabel.config(text=str(val))

Comment: and here is part 2:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1274, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1265, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
TclError: invalid command name ".3065381132L"

Comment: @HamzaBoughraira: please edit your question to include that information. it's impossible to read in a comment.

Comment: ok sir, everything is ok now, thanks a lot, it was my mistake, I destroyed my app in while loop!!!! but sir, I couldn't add error message, it appeared like a code!! and an error message appear when I try post the question, anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

import sys

import tkinter

from time import sleep

import pyfirmata # not in wondows

from pyfirmata import util # not in wondows

def press():

  it = util.Iterator(board)

  it.start()

  while True:

    if flag.get():

        analoglabel.config(text=str(pin.read()))

        analoglabel.update_idletasks()

        root.update()

    else:

        break

    board.exit()

    root.destroy()

def exit_command():

 flag.set(False)

port = '/dev/ttyACM0'

board = pyfirmata.Arduino(port) # not in wondows

sleep(5)

pin = board.get_pin('a:0:i') # not in wondows

root = tkinter.Tk()

root.title("Analog read by hamzawi")

root.minsize(300, 50)

start_button = tkinter.Button(root, text='start', command=press)

start_button.grid(column=1, row=2)

exit_button = tkinter.Button(root, text="EXIT", command=exit_command)

exit_button.grid(column=2, row=2)

label = tkinter.Label(root,

                   text="The value is: ")

label.grid(column=1, row=1)

analoglabel = tkinter.Label(root, text=" ")

analoglabel.grid(column=2, row=1)

flag = tkinter.BooleanVar()

flag.set(True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. Also please look at reformatting your code, it seems like indentation might be off but also there's a lot of unnecessary blank lines in there.

Answer (score 0):

The first time through your loop all is well. You then destroy the root window. The next time through the loop you try to configure the label widget, but it has been destroyed.

Are you sure you want to destroy the root window inside your loop?